# How to get Genes from NCBI And save it as Mat file

Tags: matlab, bioinformatics

I am Trying to get the genpept with matlab
to use it with sequences Alignment :

```
humanProtein = getgenpept('NP_000511');
```

but it shows this Error:

```
> Error using getncbidata (line 191) The key NP_000511 was not found in
> the protein database at this time. Please check that the input is a
> valid accession number or try again.
```

but the protien NP_000511 was found on the NCBI webiste On this Link:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/search/?term=NP_000511 
Can some one Help me with How to get info and how to save it As MAT file ?

Comment: Have you tried adding the version number: `humanProtein = getgenpept('NP_000511.2');`.

Comment: @Vince Yes, but still the same problem